# How to get a grand total from count in a pivot table

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get a pivot table showing the grand total at the end of the row.  Is this possible..However, i'm not able to get it to work. I have the data with the count, but i cannot get the total for each row.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
select sch.name, s.grade, s.schid, count(s.schid), 
       ( select count(ss.schid) from students ss 
         where ss.enroll_status=0 
           and ss.schid = s.schid 
         group by ss.schid) as Total
from students s
inner join schools sch on
s.schid = sch.schloc
where s.enroll_status=0
group by sch.name,s.grade, s.schid
order by sch.name,s.schid, s.grade;
```

This is what how it appears

```
|School          |Grade |Loc      |Count  |Total |
|Amery Middle    |7     |2740     |233    | 813  |
|Amery Middle    |8     |2740     |218    | 813  |
|Porter Elem     |3     |12830    |2      | 68   |
|Porter Elem     |4     |12830    |2      | 68   |
```

this is how it needs to appear in a pivot table:The Schools in rows with grades in columns showing the count, and then the grand total across for the school total enrollment

```
|                |count|count|count|count|count |count|Grand Total|
|School          |3rd  |4th  |5th  |6th  |7th   |8th  |           |
|Amery Middle    |2    |2    |0    |0    |0     |0    |868        |
|Porter Elem     |0    |0    |0    |0    |233   |218  |813        |
```

Thank you for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT NAME,
       "Count 3rd",
       "Count 4th",
       "Count 5th",
       "Count 6th",
       "Count 7th",
       "Count 8th",
       "Count 3rd" +
         "Count 4th" +
         "Count 5th" +
         "Count 6th" +
         "Count 7th" +
         "Count 8th" "Grand Total"
FROM   (SELECT sch.name,
               s.grade,
               s.schid
        FROM   students s
               INNER JOIN schools sch ON s.schid = sch.schloc
        WHERE  s.enroll_status = 0)
PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR (grade) IN (3 AS "Count 3rd",
                                4 AS "Count 4th",
                                5 AS "Count 5th",
                                6 AS "Count 6th",
                                7 AS "Count 7th",
                                8 AS "Count 8th"));
```

This assumes that the grand total column is the sum of the students in all the grades (i.e. that all students are in a grade) and that all grades have been selected.

Comment: Thank you for your assistant...do you know if there is a way to select distinct?  When i select 'DISTINCT' in either query is removes all data and shows '1' for the each grade column.  I'm getting a couple of duplicates that are throwing the count off a bit.  Thank you for any assistance given!

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question, complete with data and expected output (as you did with this question - thanks for that, btw!).